# O que significa o erro de compilação dereferenced em Java?

Tags: java, string

Em um código de teste (em Java), cujo o objetivo era converter uma *string* em uma outra *string* intercalando as letras entre maiúsculas e minúsculas, recebi o erro a seguir no momento da compilação:

> error: char cannot be dereferenced
>
> result = letter.toLowerCase();

A seguir o código de exemplo:

```
public void solve(String text) {
    int len = text.length();
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(len);
    
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        char letter = text.charAt(i);
        char result;
        
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            result = letter.toUpperCase(); //error: compile time
        else
            result = letter.toLowerCase(); //error: compile time
            
        buffer.append(result);
    }
    
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
}

solve("Teste");

// Resultado esperado:
// TeStE
```

Por que o erro acontece e o que significa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A variável `letter` é um `char`, que é um tipo primitivo de dado (um inteiro de 16 bits sem sinal). Não é um objeto. Se fosse um objeto (como por exemplo uma `String` ou um `Character`) você poderia chamar métodos nele como `letter.toUpperCase()`. Mas não é um objeto, então isso não é possível.

Se você trabalhar com os métodos estáticos utilitários da classe `Character` fica mais fácil fazer a conversão para maiúscula ou minúscula como você está querendo:

```
char letter = text.charAt(i);
char result;

if (i % 2 == 0)
    result = Character.toUpperCase(letter);
else
    result = Character.toLowerCase(letter);

buffer.append(result);
```

Comment: Nesse caso não se está usando `Character` como um *wrapper*, simplesmente usando os métodos estáticos da classe `Character`. Se fosse para usar como *wrapper*, em muitos casos o próprio *autobox* / *autounbox* se encarregaria da conversão (embora acho que isso não vale pra chamada de métodos). Entretanto, a classe `Character` só tem esses métodos que interessam como estáticos mesmo, de modo que sua abordagem está correta.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Tem razão. Corrigi a resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Você está usando um tipo primitivo. A sintaxe utilizada deve pegar uma referência na variável utilizada e tipos primitivos não possuem referência, elas guardam o valor direto sem nenhuma referência. Por isso houve um problema de *não referência* (*dereferenced*). Você tem que chamar o método estático que não trabalha com referências e passar o caractere como parâmetro normal. Utilize diretamente a classe [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) para isto.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        solve("Teste");
    }
    public static void solve(String text) {
        int len = text.length();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            char letter = text.charAt(i);
            buffer.append(i % 2 == 0 ? Character.toUpperCase(letter) : Character.toLowerCase(letter));
        }
        System.out.println(buffer);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0rbKuF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fnncdyyz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/HandleCharFromString.java).